# Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'float'

Tags: c#

```
***
```

> using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using
> UnityEngine; public class Knockback : MonoBehaviour {
> public float thrust;
> public float KnockTime;
>
> ```
> // Start is called before the first frame update
> void Start()
> {
>     
> }
> // Update is called once per frame
> void Update()
> {
>     
> }
> private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
> {
>     if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
>     {
>         Rigidbody2D enemy = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
>         if(enemy != null)
>         {
>             StartCoroutine(KnockCo(enemy));
>         }
>     }
> }
> private IEnumerator KnockCo(Rigidbody2D enemy)
> {
>     if(enemy != null)
>     {
>         Vector2 forceDirection = enemy.transform.position - transform.position;
>         Vector2 force = forceDirection.Normalize() * thrust;
>         
>         enemy.velocity = force;
>         yield return new WaitForSeconds(KnockTime);
>        
>        enemy.velocity = new Vector2();
>        {
>        }
>     }
> } }
> ```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forceDirection.Normalize()` alters the `forceDirection` vector and returns `void`, rather than returning the normalized vector. So you'll need to split the `Normalize()` call and the multiplication into separate statements:

```
Vector2 forceDirection = enemy.transform.position - transform.position;
forceDirection.Normalize();
Vector2 force = forceDirection * thrust;
```